# regex to find postition between two markers in string

Tags: python, regex

i need to find anything between

```
show_detail&amp;
```

and

```
;session_id=1445045
```

in

`https://www.site.gov.uk//search/cgi-bin/contract_search/contract_search.cgi?rm=show_detail&amp;id=4035219;num=1;session_id=1445045;start=0;recs=20;subscription=1;value=0`

using regex in python.

i know i need to use lookbehind/ahead but i can't seem to make it work!

please help!

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> s= "https://www.site.gov.uk//search/cgi-bin/contract_search/contract_search.cgi?rm=show_detail&amp;id=4035219;num=1;session_id=1445045;start=0;recs=20;subscription=1;value=0"
>>> s.split(";session_id=1445045")[0].split("show_detail&amp;")[-1]
'id=4035219;num=1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Why use a regex?

```
>>>> url = 'https://ww.site.gov.....'
>>> start = url.index('show_detail&amp;') + len('show_detail&amp;')
>>> end = url.index(';session_id=')
>>> url[start:end]
'id=4035219;num=1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a non greedy match (.*?) in between your markers.

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "https://www.site.gov.uk//search/cgi-bin/contract_search/contract_search.cgi?rm=show_detail&amp;id=4035219;num=1;session_id=1445045;start=0;recs=20;subscription=1;value=0"
>>> m = re.search("show_detail&amp;(.*?);session_id=1445045", url)
>>> m.group(1)
'id=4035219;num=1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=show_detail&amp;).*?(?=;session_id=1445045)"
```

should work. See here for more info on [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


url = "https://www.site.gov.uk//search/cgi-bin/contract_search/contract_search.cgi?rm=show_detail&amp;id=4035219;num=1;session_id=1445045;start=0;recs=20;subscription=1;value=0"
pattern = "([^>].+)(show_detail&amp;)([^>].+)(session_id=1445045)([^>].+)"
reg = re.compile(r''''''+pattern+'''''',flags = re.S)
match =reg.search(url)

print match.group(3)
```

this would work i think